# When did Luffy meet his father again in person?

Tags: one-piece

When did **Luffy** meet his father (**Dragon**) again in *One Piece*?

Comment: any possibility in future??

Comment: that is only an assumption that we can make. There has been no canonical proof of it as yet.

Answer (score 8):

In chapter 100, was the only time they met. Dragon stopped Smoker from capturing his son Luffy. Despite the fact that they never actually talked to each other, this is the only moment we know Dragon and Luffy met, since Luffy began his journey.

[image]

Comment: i was actually going to ask OP after which meeting

Comment: @mirroroftruth Has there been a second meeting?

Comment: no i don't remember and OP's question is not clear. though you answered it